# Windows font directory doesn't display all fonts installed

Tags: windows, fonts

My Windows Fonts directory only displays 22 fonts, while i have around 1000 fonts installed. How do I unhide the remaining fonts?

When i view the fonts using BitStream Navigator I can view all fonts.

Comment: Just because files are in `C:\Windows\Fonts` doesn't mean that they're "installed".  What's in the registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`?

Comment: solved this by running word in safe mode (run that: winword /safe ), create  new doc, write and see if your font appear. It did for me, close the word-safe-mode, reopen your doc just by clicking on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows 7 you can show and hide fonts via the Control Panel.  Specifically `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Fonts`.

Once there, highlight the fonts you want visible and click "Show".

Additionally (and less Win7-specific), depending on your access, you may also be able to access the Fonts folder as a "regular" folder by using it's network UNC path:

`\\localhost\c$\Windows\Fonts`

Once there you can check and set hidden attributes on the font files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a post saying this problem was related to some printer drivers.  I uninstalled my canon printer and the driver, rebooted, printer and driver automatically reinstalled and problem solved!  Good luck.